# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame when using df.filter(regex=) and assigning the result to a variable

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a dataframe that we can import with `import pandas as pd; df=pd.clipboard()`.

```
Index   Unnamed: 1  HLA A1_D    HLA A2_D    HLA B1_D    HLA B2_D    HLA C1_D    HLA C2_D    DRB11_D DRB12_D DQB11_D DQB12_D Unnamed: 12 HLA A1_R    HLA A2_R    HLA B1_R    HLA B2_R    HLA C1_R    HLA C2_R    DRB11_R DRB12_R DQB11_R DQB12_R
1       A*01:01 A*32:01 B*38:01 B*44:02 C*05:01 C*12:03 DRB1*04:01  DRB1*04:02  DQB1*03:02  DQB1*03:02      A*01:01 A*32:01 B*38:01 B*44:02 C*05:01 C*12:03 DRB1*04:01  DRB1*04:02  DQB1*03:01  DQB1*03:02
2       A*24:02 A*30:01 B*07:02 B*13:02 C*06:02 C*07:02 DRB1*04:05  DRB1*15:01  DQB1*03:02  DQB1*06:02      A*24:02 A*30:01 B*07:02 B*13:02 C*06:02 C*07:02 DRB1*04:04  DRB1*15:01  DQB1*03:02  DQB1*06:02
```

When I do
`df_dddd = df.filter(regex='_D')`
and then
`df_dddd.drop([1], axis=0, inplace=True)`

I get the following warning:

```py
<input>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

I've read the documentation, but I don't understand how it applies to me. `df_ddddd` is a slice from a DataFrame, but it's been put into a variable so it should be enough for pandas to understand that it's not "just" a slice from a DataFrame anymore, right?

Comment: Likely `df_dddd = df.filter(regex='_D').copy()`. Also objects are not "aware" of variables pointing to them.

Comment: Ohhhh ok I guess this makes sense. It's a shame pandas cannot detect it :(. Thank you so much!!